# Can I set a style conditional on window size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, less

I've set a style for an iframe that is a youtube video:

```
iframe {
     width: 450px !important;
     height: 253px !important;
 }
```

But if the window is resized to small size, then the left margin disappears and there is room for the original size of the iframe. Is it possible to use the original size of the iframe when the window is resized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries):

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

    iframe {
         width: 450px !important;
         height: 253px !important;
    }

}
```

The above rule will only apply if the window is at least 768px wide. There are a bunch of other things you can put on the media query to choose what it applies to — medium (screen, print, etc.), max width, and so on.